# Property delegate must have a 'getValue(donorApp, KProperty*>)' method

Tags: android, database, kotlin, dao

```
package com.example.bloodbank

import android.app.Application

class donorApp:Application(){
    val db by lazy{
        DonorDatabase.getInstance(this)
    }
}
```

I am trying to make an instance of the database to access the Dao but the lazy{} is not working it shows a error
"Property delegate must have a 'getValue(donorApp, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable"

here the donor Database

```
package com.example.bloodbank

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [DonorEntity::class], version = 2)
abstract class DonorDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun donorDao():DonorDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE:DonorDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context):DonorDatabase{
            synchronized(this){
                var instance=INSTANCE
                if (instance==null){
                    instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        DonorDatabase::class.java,"donor_database")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                }
                INSTANCE=instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

here the Dao

```
package com.example.bloodbank

import androidx.room.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface DonorDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(donorEntity:DonorEntity)
    @Update
    suspend fun update(donorEntity:DonorEntity)
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(donorEntity:DonorEntity)
    @Query("SELECT*FROM `donor-table`")
    fun fetchAllDonor(): Flow<List<DonorEntity>>
    @Query("SELECT*FROM `donor-table` Where id=:id")
    fun fetchOneDonor(id:Int): Flow<DonorEntity>
}
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace, looking at your lazy delegate, it looks okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code shouldn't even compiler because your return type is `DonorDatabase` but you are returning nullable variable. You havent added `!!` operator also.

Since `db` non nullable, you can make it like below and remove extra instance variable.

```
@Database(entities = [DonorEntity::class], version = 2)
abstract class DonorDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun donorDao():DonorDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE:DonorDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context):DonorDatabase{
            synchronized(this){
                if (INSTANCE ==null){
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        DonorDatabase::class.java,"donor_database")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                }
                return INSTANCE!!
            }
        }
    }

}
```